# javascriptとhtmlで関連記事の表示をしたい

Tags: javascript, html

事前にカテゴリを三次元配列として用意して、for文で呼び出したhtmlがどのカテゴリに該当するか調べて、そのカテゴリに含まれているページを二次元配列（ページのURLとサムネイル）で返すというプログラムを作ろうとしています。

下のようなコードを書いたのですが、画面に表示される文字がURLではなく、undefinedになります。

どのようなコードを書けば良いのでしょうか？

ブラウザ : GoogleChrome
htmlのパス : file:///D:/user1234/Documents/フォルダ/ホームページ/parts/index.html
jsのパス : file:///D:/user1234/Documents/フォルダ/ホームページ/parts/○○.js

結果として、画面にparts/index.htmlと表示したいです。

index.html

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>JavaScript 関連記事<title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Category_list.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Related_article.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
//ここで関数呼び出し
related_article("file:///D:/user1234/Documents/フォルダ/ホームページ/");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Category_list.js

```
function category_list() {
 var list = [
   [
     ["index.html", "parts/header_img.jpg"]
   ],
   [
     ["test/index.html", "test/foo.jpeg"],
     ["test/hogehoge/index.html", ""]
   ],
   [
     ["parts/index.html", "test/foo.jpeg"]
   ]
 ];

 return list;
}
```

Related_article.js

```
function get_page_array (domain) {
  //カテゴリリストを取得
  var cat_list = category_list();
  //カテゴリの数を取得
  var num_of_cat = cat_list.length;

  //カテゴリごとに調べる
  for (var c = 0; c <= (num_of_cat-1); c++) {
    var page_list = cat_list[c];
    var num_of_page = page_list.length;

    //ページごとに調べる
    for (var p = 0; p <= (num_of_page-1); p++) {
      var page_path = domain + page_list[p][0];
      //ファイルのURL(パス)とカテゴリに書かれたURLが一致すれば
      //そのカテゴリのページリストを返す
      if (location.href == page_path) {
        return page_list;
      }
    }
  }
}

function related_article (domain) {
  var related_array = get_page_array(domain);

  //undefinedになる
  document.write(related_array[0][0]);
}
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14196311659

Comment: 原因を判断するに`if (location.href == page_path) {` の前に`console.log(location.href + " === "+ page_path +" is " +　(location.href == page_path) )`とデバック文を入れてみて実行してみてください。コンソールにどのように出力されるか追記願います。

Comment: undefinedになるというのは、undefinedが表示されるということなのでしょうか。それとも`related_array`がundefinedになってエラーが起きるということなのでしょうか。後者であれば、ファイルパスに日本語が含まれていることが問題かもしれません。`location.href`は`"file:///D:/user1234/Documents/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%80/%E3%83%9B%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8/parts/index.html"`のようになっているはずです。

Comment: console.log(location.href + " === "+ page_path +" is " + (location.href == page_path) );を追加すると、  `file:///D:/user1234/Documents/%E3%83%89%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88/%E3%83%9B%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8/parts/index.htm === file:///D:/user1234/Documents/フォルダ/ホームページ/index.html,parts/head_img.jpg is false`
と表示されました。

Comment: undefinedになるというのは、undefinedが表示されるということです。
説明不足ですみませんでした。

Comment: 現在質問文にあるコードだと、そのような動作はしないように思います。`cat_list`の中身がなんだか変なので、`Category_list.js`の中身がどうなっているかや、ちゃんと正しい`Category_list.js`を読み込んでいるかなどをもう一度見なおしたほうがよいと思います。

Comment: デバッグツールで確認してみたところ、cat_listの中身は正常でした。
そのまま変数の値を確認してみたところ、page_pathにURLと画像のパスが含まれていました。なので`page_list[p][0]`に変更し、`document.write(related_array);`も`document.write(related_array[0][0]);`
に変更しました。
`location.href`の値も確認すると、日本語がパーセントエンコーディングになっていたため、コメント通り置き換えることで無事、parts/index.htmlと表示できるようになりました。

Comment: @yutodes さん、お疲れ様でした。問題が解決したということであれば、スタック・オーバーフローでは[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)を推奨しています！　同じ問題で困った人のためにも、是非お願いいたします<(\_ \_)>　また、コメントの内容を受けて FailyFeely さんが別に回答いただくことも大歓迎です<(\_ \_)>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.htmlの title の閉じるタグに / が入っていません。
正しくは
`<title>JavaScript 関連記事</title>`
です。これで動作しました。